# Windows Store App c# replace SQL Database in local storage

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, copy, local-storage

I am trying to overwrite the database in my local folder with one that is in my pictures directory I use the following

```
StorageFolder storageFolder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;
        String picName = "SqlLiteWin8-1.db";
        var file2 = await storageFolder.TryGetItemAsync(picName) as IStorageFile;
        StorageFile fileCopy = await file2.CopyAsync(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, "SqlLiteWin8-1.db", Windows.Storage.NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

It seems to work and the file is copied and overwrite the old one
Problem is when I run the app it still shows the old data

I checked by manually deleting the db in the local state folder of the app then running the code and it copies it to the folder.
I think its still using the database in the app package and not the one in the local folder

The database in the pictures directory is identical to the one stored in the app except 1 record is modified

I want to overwrite it so that I can just supply a new db file to users and the app will use the new data or is there a way of bypassing this and read the DB straight from the pictures directory instead of the local folder

one though was it uses the following code to check if the db exists and copies if it doesnt could this be what is causing it not to work

```
public static async Task<bool> checkDataBaseConnection()
    {
        bool isDatabaseExisting = false;

        try
        {
            var uri = new Uri("ms-appx:///SqlLiteWin8-1.db"); //in application folder  
            var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri);

            var destinationFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;//local appdata dir  

            //await file.DeleteAsync(); 
            // var f = await destinationFolder.GetFileAsync("data.db3");  

            await file.CopyAsync(destinationFolder); 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
            isDatabaseExisting = false;
        }

        if (!isDatabaseExisting)
        {
            StorageFile databaseFile = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("AFSMOJO.db");
            await databaseFile.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);
        }
        return isDatabaseExisting;

    }
```

As always your help is greatly appreciated

Mark

Answer (score -1):

Ignore my stupidity I found what was wrong I was connecting to the internal database instead of the local one

I changed

var db = new SQLiteConnection("SqlLiteWin8-1.db");

to

var db = new SQLiteConnection(Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "SqlLiteWin8-1.db"));

and now i can change my db in the picture folder and it copies it to the local one and uses the new data

Thanks

Mark